# Implements Runnable over Extends Thread with EJB

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, code-injection, runnable

Let's say the class `MyCoolProcess` has the logic of my app which is needed to be called in it's own thread. We'll create a thread, call it and continue with the application.
This class is a EJB; annotated with `@Stateless`

Now we have the `MyController` class; which is going to call a new thread.

Code:

```
public class MyController {

  @EJB
  MyCoolProcess p;

  public Response foo() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        p.run();
      }
    };
    t.start();
    // continues ...
  }

 }
```

---

```
@Stateless
public class MyCoolProcess {

  public void run() {
    // heavy task
  }
}
```

That is *working fine*; the point is... before that solution I've tried with the `Runnable` interface. Which was I wanted at first time. The approach would be:

```
public class MyController {

  @EJB
  MyCoolProcess p;

  public Response foo() {
    Thread t = new Thread(p);
    t.start();
    // continues ...
  }

 }
```

---

```
@Stateless
public class MyCoolProcess implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // heavy task
  }
}
```

That doesn't work. Actually, the server cannot start. Crashes trying to inject the dependencies. I'm not be able to implement the interface `Runnable` if I'm a EJB isn't it? **WHY**

And... is there any way to do the `Runnable` way instead the anonymous class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the EJB spec:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage thread groups.

See [Adam's Blog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/conveniently_transactionally_and_legally_starting).